# The pages on my website end with .html.html - Is this a problem?

Tags: html, magento2.4

The category and product pages on my website look like this:

ex: www.mywebsite/category/sub-category.html.html

My website is being hosted with Magento 2. This is only happening to product pages, not the static html pages like /about-us and those kinds of pages.

When I remove one of the .html's from the url, it says page not found so it does need both. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: change the actual file name and change the url.  If you change one and not the other it obviously won't work

Answer (score 0):

remove `.html.html` from the file name. That should work.